# Only QwtPlot working. No graph in PyQtGraph and MatPlot

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to plot my data and are having some trouble.
The problem is that only QwtPlot is able to plot my data. I like PyQtGraph the best so i would like to use this. At first glance it looks like it doesn't receive any data, but when i look at the Y-axis it autoscrolls according to the data on the topic. The X-axis is not moving thou.

I am able to plot other topics with both PyQtGraph and MatPlot, so this is an event only occuring when plotting this topic.

This is the message I am sending:

Header header

string[] name
float64[] position
float64[] velocity
float64[] effort

I am trying to get the position on the plot.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172326/only-qwtplot-working.-no-graph-in-pyqtgraph-and-matplot/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do the messages you're sending have the timestamp in the header set properly?

The matplotlib and pyqtgraph plots use the timestamps for the X axis, and the qwtplot plots only use the received message order.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2014-05-31**:
Probably not. How do I do that?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-31**:
Before you publish your message, just do

```
msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

in C++ or

```
msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
```

in python.

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2014-05-31**:
NICE. Thanks :D